# Scripts are not getting rendered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

Cshtml code.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datefield", type = "date" } })

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery")
}
```

Bundle.config code

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jquery").Include(
   "~/Scripts/jqueryui1.12.s",
   "~/Scripts/jqueryui-12.js",   
    "~/Scripts/DateTimePicket.js"
));     

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/jqueryui1.12.css"
));
```

code of DateTimePicker

```
$(function () {
    alert("hi");
    $(".datefield").datepicker();
});
```

where is the issue.
The code of these file `"~/Scripts/jqueryui1.12.s", "~/Scripts/jqueryui-12.js",` are from

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I am just trying to add the datepicker and the code got messed up.

Comment: I can share the project also.. if required...

Comment: ya please share

Comment: are you getting any error in the browser console??

Comment: How can I share the project here ?

Comment: @Umamaheswaran I am not getting any issue in the console

Comment: The issue is resolved.The class was not getting bind to the control. I changed this code$(function () {
    alert("hi");
    $("#StartDate").datepicker();
});

Answer (score 0):

if design is going messy then it will definitely shows the errors in browser console.First you should find out which js erros are coming..

and you have placed jquery file **~/Scripts/DateTimePicket.js.** Is this "**DateTimePicket**" or "**DateTimePicker**" ?? If its spelling mistake then also it can create issue as well..

And if this is not spelling mistake then check with second scenario, you have created section scripts but have u used @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) in layout? Or you can try by adding your renders at the top of the cshtml code as below.

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery")
```

with Not creating any section,try directly renders.

Comment: Please check with my modified text above

Comment: I have added all the scripts in the Create.cshtml page. Layout page has the Render section.

Comment: The issue is resolved.The class was not getting bind to the control. I changed this code$(function () {
    alert("hi");
    $("#StartDate").datepicker();
});

Answer (score 0):

I think the Issue is you are trying to add css and javascript also please cross the spelling of the DateTimePicker js file

You render css in cshtml you need to use the below line

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Nope...Tried with the Styles but still not getting anything.